# How to perform certain calculations in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Just trying to create a simple sheet to track my weight loss. Here is a link to my sheet so far so you can see what I'm talking about. [Weight Loss Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zldtFy1x3uuvg6n-Ce-cCQN0BQEbSK6zwDFYgsnzCBc/edit?usp=sharing)

So far I have gotten the **C** column working properly. Now I just need help with **D** and **E**.

1: In **D** (I have added examples) I would like it to calculate the difference between the current and previous weight entry with a formula that can auto-fill (keeping in mind that entries are often separated by sporadic empty cells). So each number in **C** minus the entry above it.

2: Next in **E** would like it to show the average every 7 days that will change depending on my rate of loss from **D**. Added a few manually calculated numbers as an example. Pretty sure I have calculated it wrong though. Arg! Should have stayed in school :)

This is my very first time using sheets so I am an absolute beginner. Never even used Excel. I have tried googling for a solution but I couldn't find anything. I think the problem is I don't know exactly what to search for.

Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Groups helped me more than I could have asked for. Here is what they gave me!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zldtFy1x3uuvg6n-Ce-cCQN0BQEbSK6zwDFYgsnzCBc/edit?usp=sharing